# jquery get not allowing x[i] inside of function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a JQuery get that returns true if there is an embedded youtube video at the other end of the URL, and if so update the div to mention that.
My Code so far:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("videoplace");
var lim=x.length;
for (var i = 0; i <lim; i++) {
        $.get(x[i].innerHTML, function(data){if(data.indexOf("youtube.com/embed")>-1)
        {
            x[i].innerHTML = "Video Exists";
        }
        });
}
```

When I run this I get an error in the console that says "TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined" I have tried a plethora of alternatives and while the get function is working, and the if only fires if it returns true correctly, it doesnt correctly recognize where to put the "Video exists" text.

Comment: `$x` is not equal to `x`

Comment: This is an instance of a "callback in a for loop with a reference to the index variable" question.

Comment: Corrected the $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the moment callback `function(data)` run `for` loop is over Correct call is

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("videoplace");
var lim=x.length;
for (var i = 0; i <lim; i++) {
        (function(j){$.get(x[j].innerHTML, function(data){if(data.indexOf("youtube.com/embed")>-1)
        {
            x[j].innerHTML = "Video Exists";
        }
        }))(i);
}
```

Comment: The closing brackets on the end of this are a little messed up, they should be in the order })}(i))} but this was the correct answer, thank you very much!

Comment: (function(){/*doIt(arg);})("doit");, (function(){/*doIt(arg);}("doit")) and !function(){/*doIt(arg);}("doit") work exactly the same. function definition must start as a new definition. Else it is a IIEF. Use it or hate it.

Comment: @theinvisibleduck I didn't  check how it works. Some small issues may appear.

Answer (score -1):

x !== $x

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("videoplace");
var lim=x.length;
for (var i = 0; i <lim; i++) {
        $.get(x[i].innerHTML, function(data){if(data.indexOf("youtube.com/embed")>-1)
        {
            x[i].innerHTML = "Video Exists";
        }
        });
}
```

Comment: Please flag as a typographical error. This question is off-topic, so please don't answer it

Comment: This won't work either, because when the callback is invoked the value of `i` will be `lim`.